# resources.ap_ detected as malware by antivirus software. How can I correct this?

Tags: android, malware, false-positive

We have Bitdefender installed at work and whenever I try to build the project it fails because ***resources.ap_*** is detected as ***Android.Adware.GingerMaster.BJ***. I hope it's obvious I'm not creating malware.

I've uploaded the it to virustotal and where gets flagged as:

- Android_dc.VUJ
- Trojan.AndroidOS.Generic.A
- Android-Malicious/GinMaster
- A.H.Pri.Hippo.A
- a.privacy.popsp.c

and a few other similar names.

I've narrowed it down to these pairs of activities: **Fyber**:

```
<activity android:name="com.sponsorpay.publisher.ofw.SPOfferWallActivity" 
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
          android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>
<activity android:name="com.sponsorpay.publisher.mbe.SPBrandEngageActivity" 
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" 
          android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>
```

and **AppLovin**:

```
<activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" 
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" 
          android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" />
<activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity" 
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" 
          android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" />
```

If I only keep **AppLovin** or **Fyber** in the manifest then it only gets flagged as ***Android.Adware.GingerMaster.BU*** instead of that whole list.

These are the permissions used:

```
GET_TASKS, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, READ_PHONE_STATE,
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, INTERNET, GET_ACCOUNTS, BILLING, CHECK_LICENSE, WAKE_LOCK
```

Obviously if I remove all the ads and all the permissions it no longer gets flagged as malware at all, but the app fails to work at that point.

Has anyone ever encountered such a problem and fixed it?
Or alternately is there a tool that can analyse an Android manifest file and tell me if I have any "suspicious" permission combinations ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question.

Comment: Edited for clarity, hopefully.

Comment: Well, I solved it myself in the end. READ_PHONE_STATE was causing the issues. After removing the permission virustotal reported the app as clean. The app works even without that permission so I have no idea how this got in here (inherited codebase).